# Why might CorelDraw's publish to pdf feature produce different size files depending on which group the executing user account is in?

Tags: permissions, coreldraw

As part of a project I am developing a web service to convert CDR files to PDF. I am using c# to trigger CorelDraw's publish to PDF feature. The conversion is run as a command line utility called by the web service.

I am hosting the web service in IIS. I have created a user account for the website's application pool in order to be able to run CorelDraw (I was unable to get it to work with the default application pool and configuring DCOM).

I am getting PDF files of different sizes depending on whether I manually log in to the account and run the conversion program or trigger it through the web service from another machine. I seem also to get different file sizes depending of whether the application pool account is in the users or administrators group.

Can anyone suggest why this might be happening and what I can do about it?

Answer (score 0):

pdf files sometimes have partial or complete typeface (font) data embedded in them. Maybe access permissions to the font source are different for the different credentials you're using and Corel is leaving them out if it doesn't have access to them.

In Adobe Reader, right click, choose Document Properties, and look at the Fonts tab. Check both the bigger and smaller pdf files, and see if they have same set of font data loaded.

Comment: Thank you for pointing me at checking the PDF properties - I feel dumb for not thinking of it. The font type and encoding were different. I have had some success setting the PDF export settings in code rather than assuming that the preset for the current user is being used. I'd still like to understand why CorelDraw behaves differently depending of whether I or IIS's application pool run my conversion code seeing as we both use the same account username and password.